# Why don't props update in a component rendered in a stack navigator in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a component (it's called CothesCategoriesList) that receives some props (the values of those props are taken from a piece of state) and that gets rendered by a Stack navigator.

I have a form that when submitted changes the state, and theoretically should change the props that are passed to the component, but this does not happen. State changes, as i have tested, but the props don't. How can i fix this? How can i make the component receive the new props?

This is code from the component that contains the Stack navigator and that renders ClosetCategoriesList:

```
<ClosetStack.Screen
        name="Categories"
        options={({ navigation }) => ({
          headerRight: props => (
            <Button
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Modal")}
              color="tomato"
              type="clear"
              icon={<Icon name="add" size={30} color="tomato" />}
            />
          )
        })}
      >
        {props => (
          <ClosetCategoriesList
            {...props}
            categories={categories_state.categories}
            navigation={props.navigation}
          />
        )}
</ClosetStack.Screen>
```

In the parent component i have some state created with the useState hook, which i change with the following handler:

```
const handleCategoryFormSubmit = category => {
    let new_categories_state = [...categories_state.categories];
    new_categories_state.push({
      title: category.category_name,
      subcategories: []
    });
    set_categories_state({ categories: new_categories_state });
  };
```

Then in the component that renders each individual element i have the following code that receives as props the state from the parent component (categories):

```
let parsed = categories.map((category, index) => (
    <ListItem
      key={index}
      title={category.title}
      bottomDivider
      onPress={() =>
        navigation.push("Subcategories", {
          subcategory_index: index
        })
      }
    />
  ));
  return <View>{parsed}</View>;
```

The modal form has the following code, and i suspect that because i use navigation to go back to the Categories component, the state does not persist, and the component is rendered with the hard-coded state.

```
<Formik
        initialValues={{ category_name: "" }}
        onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
          handleCategoryFormSubmit(values);
          actions.resetForm();
          navigation.navigate("Categories");
        }}
      >
```

Comment: It depends on other things as well like how you are handling props in the receiving components in your case ClosetCategoriesList. Have you implemented componentDidUpdate or componentDidReceive method , which are called when props are changed.

Answer (score 0):

It could be for so many different reasons since we don't know how you handle your state change in the parent component

1)If you are not using setState to update your state, react will not re-render the component. Avoid changing the state without using setState

2)Update child to have attribute 'key' equal to name. The component will re-render every time the key changes e.g

```
render() {
    return <div key={this.props.bar}>{this.props.bar}</div>
}
```

3)Use componentDidUpdate to check if your props change and you can update your state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i don't think that really helps.I have updated the question to provide more details.